# Is there a type that essentially acts as a non-primitive any

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to set a type that will act like `any`, but will not allow primitive values to be assigned?

```
type Demogorgon = { friendly: boolean };
const sarah: Demogorgon = { friendly: true };
const duck = 'is in the upside down';

let anyNonPrimitive: any;   // What type can replace 'any' and make the following comments true?

anyNonPrimitive = duck;     // should fail assignment    
anyNonPrimitive = sarah;    // should allow assignment

console.log(anyNonPrimitive.friendly);  // property 'friendly' should be accessible
console.log(anyNonPrimitive.unicorns);  // does not cause type error, returns undefined
```

Comment: What's your use case? Do you want `anyNonPrimitive.friendly` to be recognized as boolean?

Comment: @Tao, that's correct.

Comment: I still don't get what's your use case. Why don't you just use the `Demogorgon` type?

Comment: @Tao, the real use case is adding a fairly unrestrictive type to the result of a JSON API where the result can be any non-primitive type.

Comment: does it have to be type or can it be interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Tao, the real use case is adding a fairly unrestrictive type to the result of a JSON API where the result can be any non-primitive type.

You can use indexed types, which allow any key of a specific type. For a loose JSON it could be something like this.

```
interface JsonObject {
    [key: string]: JsonValue
}

interface JsonArray extends Array<JsonValue> {}

type JsonValue = null | string | number | boolean | JsonArray | JsonObject;
```

Now, if you want to extend a strong interface you could intersect it with `JsonObject`.

```
let anyNonPrimitive: JsonObject & Demogorgon;

anyNonPrimitive = duck;     // error    
anyNonPrimitive = sarah;    // works

console.log(anyNonPrimitive.friendly);  // 'friendly' is boolean
console.log(anyNonPrimitive.unicorns);  // 'unicorns' is JsonValue
```